# How to insert value at specified index?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have Parent table and Child table with one to many relationship:

```
List<Child> list = new LinkedList<>("1","2","3","5","6");
```

I'm trying this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createQuery("from Parent where id= :id");
query.setLong("id", parent_id);
Parent parent = (Parenr) query.uniqueResult();
List<Child> children = parent.getChildren();
children.set(2, "4");
session.update(parent);
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

but get the value inserted into the end of the list

("1","2","3","5","6","4")

If I print out the list before committing transaction, the list is ordered correctly: ("1","2","3","4","5","6")
But after transaction is committed, the value is inserted into the end. Maybe there is something wrong with SQL script?

How to insert it correctly?

Comment: What's the issue? is it inserting at the end?

Comment: I actually am trying to insert at index 2

Comment: whats the primary key for child? can you post both parent and child entities?

Comment: You think it may be strategy = GenerationType issue?

Comment: @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    private long id;

Comment: Parent parent = (Parenr) query.uniqueResult(); is incorrect. You meant to case to parent, not parenr.

Comment: It is just a typo in my post, not in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the value is inserted?, i ask because from what i know, set() allow you to replace the value that exist in that index.

So if you have `("1","2","3","5","6")` and you do a `children.set(2,"4")`, now you will have `("1","2","4","5","6")`.

i recommend use add() and specify the index like this `children.add(2,"4")` and the expected result should be `("1","2","4","3","5","6")`.

PD: Also i don't know if this cause you a problem, but when you do the cast of the uniqueResult() you have (Parenr) and it should be (Parent).

Comment: Yes I am sure. In my case, for some reason, methods add(index, value) and  set(index, value) work the same way: append the value to the end of the list.

Comment: Can you please add Parent and Child classes to your code?, maybe i can reproduce the problem (well a part since i don't have your database) and try to find a solution.

Comment: I dont think it's a good idea, but thanks anyways. My question is addressed to those, who are experienced in hibernate. No need to upload all the code.